# in_app_purchase giving error "Your transaction can't be completed. To continue this transaction, use a different payment instrument or contact us"

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

when user tries to purchase product from my flutter application with card method after filling card details and tap on buy/subscribe its giving error like,
`"Your transaction can't be completed. To continue this transaction, use a different payment instrument or contact us"`. is there any way to resolve this error from flutter side?.
Error screenshot is shared below.[image]